# write code on assembly language for android application

Tags: java, android, assembly

i have a very large list of String...(ArraList myList) and i want to remove duplicated items from this list very fast..i copied the items into a HashMap, that's the best algorithm i found but yet it is not fast enough...
 i have found some thing like writing code using native languages and implement it in android app, can we  remove the duplication from the list using native language, is there any function written by assembly language that can do this faster than java can do?

if not, is there a function that can just  compare two strings faster than java can do ?

Comment: No. Assembler can not magically remove algorithmic complexity. Why do you have it in a `ArrayList` instead of a `Set` to begin with?

Comment: HashMap? Why not HashSet?

Comment: i have List<Contact>.. now i want to remove the duplication using Contact.write() method... this method returns the contact with all its contents as a string..

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question, it is possible to program in C for Android using [NDK](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html). And, as the way from C to Assembler is rather short, may be possible in Assembler as well. And while Java performance is currently rather good, a claim no language ever could check an array for duplicates faster seems for me somewhat an overestimation.

However switching between languages is complex, and for the task so trivial you may loose performance by just accessing your array an [JNI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/intro.html#wp725) level.

It may be more reasonable to rethink the algorithm. For instance:

- If you just need to iterate over the list but must have it ordered, use `LinkedHashSet`. This will prevent the duplicate items from beginning.
- If you have a lot of duplicates, the removal operation may be too expensive as big parts of the array may be moved a lot of times. Try to set items to be removed to null instead and then recreate the array from scratch skipping nulls.

Answer (score 0):

> is there any function written by assembly language that can do this faster than java can do?

Does such a function already exist?  I don't know ... and I don't know how one would find it if it did.

Could you write such a function?  Maybe ... in theory.

- Assume that there is a function that performs this task as fast as theoretically possible (in some context).
- No matter what language that function is written in, it should be possible to find out what machine code the function compiler (or assembles) to.
- Having done that, you can turn that machine code into assembler ... giving an assembly language function that performs the task with maximum performance.
- And since such an assembler program can exist (in theory), a sufficiently smart / skilled / patient human being could (in theory) write it ... from scratch!

But the problem is that you would need to be a really good assembler programmer (with a really good understanding of the algorithms involved) to be able to pull this off.  And the kicker is there is no guarantee that the existing Java implementation (when compiled using a good JIT compiler) won't be almost as fast.

The reason I'm being pessimistic here is that implementing an efficient hash table in an HLL (like Java) is hard enough for most people.  Achieving the same think in assembly language is going to be orders of magnitude harder.  (That's rhetorical.  You can't really *quantify* difficulty like that ...)

---

> if not, is there a function that can just compare two strings faster than java can do ?

I don't see how this will help much.  If you are using a `HashSet` properly, then String comparison should not be the performance bottleneck for your problem.  Not even if your ratio of duplicates is high.

Comment: It is not cleat to me yet, but if i didn't get it wrong.. using 'Java Native Interface' you avoid passing through the JIT compiler.. my question is.. " what if, just by moving the data of the list to the assembler function by parameters and getting the cleaned list again as 'return', the code will consume all the time that i am trying to avoid.. by moving the list to the hashset.. what is the most part of the function that cause delay..

Answer (score 0):

Where you get and store your strings list? May be using SQLite or somethin like [CQEngine](https://code.google.com/p/cqengine/) to store and manage data will be better?

Comment: Answer questions in an answer....don't ask more.  That's what the comments section is for

Comment: i am reading my strings from files( 5000 vcf files).. is there any way to compare the contacts of two files and deleting one of them if they are the same.. ?